# Text Direction in Phaser.js

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I would like to know if there is any text direction on Phaser.js Text class
like when user input some text, then the text input in the canvas will have a text direction of right to left or left to right;

and I'm implementing this on whole canvas application

example in the normal html we can attain this using the css properties

```
 direction:ltr,

   direction:rtl
```

anyone has any idea on how to do it.

i was reading on the phaser.js text class but cannot find any properties to set the direction to right to left but no luck.

thanks in advance;

Comment: @Cherniv no, do you have any ways to do it?

Comment: For hebrew i'm using this method: https://jsfiddle.net/xgk454nz/ , but i don't know if it will work with arabic..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I can't find any documentation on the phaser to make this happen
then i simply just make a work around to look like i am able to make the direction
of the text to be right align.

Here is a simple text

```
var txt = this.game.add.text(10, 10, '0', {
    font: "21px arial", 
    fill: "#00FF00", 
    align:'right', 
    fontWeight:'bold',
});
```

compute for the new position x of the txt

formula :

> txt.x = contant - txt.width

the constant will be a reference point you want to offset
according to your positioning

so when the variable txt text updated

then you can re-position it again using
the the new data

```
txt.setText(100);

txt.x = 84 - (txt.width);
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like phaser text now supports rtl through this class:

```
Phaser.GameObjects. TextStyle
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
yourApplication.canvas.setAttribute("dir", "rtl");
```

... where yourApplication holds the reference to your game/application. This adds an attribute to the DOM canvas element your game/application draws to (if that's what you're after).

Comment: have you tried.? because the code will only add an attribute to the canvas dir = rtl